# How do I parse an Angular $http response that doesnt have an escaped double quote?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, http, escaping

I have this Object returning from a search endpoint that has an attribute that can have a value as such(notice the double quote in the string):

```
{
     ...,
    description: "24" curtain rod",
     ...
}
```

When I go to capture the response with:

```
promise
  .then(function(data) {
    vm.displayData = data.search_results;
  })
```

Note: The JSON is returned correctly, escaped as such:

`{..., "description": "24\" curtain rod", ... }`

My problem is, I cannot for the life of me figure out why when I then do this:

```
console.log(vm.displayData)
```

the `description` attribute is set to `undefined` in the browser console. If I just reference this attribute directly (assuming its first in the array) within the `.then()` block using `data.search_results[0].description`, it will *correctly* print `24" curtain rod`. I found a potential fix by defining a `transformResponse` attribute in my `$http` request but I feel like theres a much easier and less complicated way. What could that be?

PS: For some perhaps useful context, the `vm.displayData` object is given to UI-Grid to render a data table. The table cell where the description is displayed is also inline-editable, in an `md-input` element.

Comment: Is the `console.log` statement "outside" the `.then` block?

Comment: It is inside the ```then``` block.

Comment: I find your code and question very disjointed. The code is chopped into 4 tiny pieces and the narrative doesn't connect well. A JSON is returned correctly. A console.log is `undefined`. Something has an embedded double quote. Something doesn't have a double quote. It's hard to know what is going on and what is going wrong. Something needs to be fixed but what and why?